# Access violation with strcat()

Tags: c, string, concatenation, c-strings, strcat

In my code i have a for loop to concat char by char from another array starting from a certain point. So  for example if the text is "hi i need help" and my starting index is 10 it would concat "help" to the end of char* rs.

```
for (int l = start_index; l < strlen(text); l++) {
    strcat(rs, "h");
}
```

I tested the above and it works fine with no errors, but this

```
for (int l = start_index; l < strlen(text); l++) {
    strcat(rs, text[l]);
}
```

does not. According to the debugger "text" is char[256] and "rs" is a *char if that helps. The debugger also shows text[l] is of the correct value in that enumeration.

Comment: Enable all your compiler warnings.

Comment: A `char` is no string.

Comment: "According to the debugger..." If this is your code, why not just look at the definition instead of what the debugger thinks it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) function takes two *strings* (pointers to `char`) as arguments. From the context it seems that `text[l]` is a single `char` which can't be used.

One way to work around that is to create a small one-character temporary string for the character:

```
for (int l = start_index; l < strlen(text); l++) {
    char temp[] = { text[l], '\0' };  // Don't forget the terminator
    strcat(rs, temp);
}
```

Another solution is to not use `strcat` at all, and instead use indexing of the `rs` string to assign directly to the elements of the string:

```
size_t end_of_rs = strlen(rs);
for (int l = start_index; l < strlen(text); l++) {
    rs[end_of_rs++] = text[l];
}
rs[end_of_rs] = '\0';  // Make sure string is terminated
```

Or a much simpler solution: Concatenate directly from `text`:

```
strcat(rs, &text[start_index]);
```

But for this you should make sure that `start_index` isn't beyond the end of `text` (i.e. you need to verify that `start_index < strlen(text)`).

Comment: Or, `strcat(rs, text + start_index)`. Ok, beat me to it. To make it functionally equivalent, I would also add a check to see if `start_index` exceeds `strlen(text)`.

Comment: @Groo Added something similar at the same time you wrote your comment :) But the safety check is a good idea that I added.

Comment: ...or do `strcat(rs, (char[2]){text[l]});` The `0`-terminator is set by default initialisation, as BTW, it would be done here as well: `char temp[2] = {text[l]};`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! i didn't know such a distinction existed. It works now

Comment: @alk: I believe this one-liner would raise a bunch of eyebrows during code reviews, though. :)

Comment: @IanLee Then I'm sorry to say that you need to take a step back and refresh your basic C knowledge.